How to correctly override retrofit baseUrl or okhttp.Request URL inside okhttp.Interceptor?
I have a situation where, URLs for my requests have to change, based on some conditions.
Basically, I construct my okHttpClient instance and add an interceptor to it.
Here, I check if I have to change the request url or not.
Code looks like this:
private val interceptor: Interceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
    val request = chain.request()
    val originalRequest: Request = chain.request()
    val replacedUrl = originalRequest.url.toString().replace(originalRequest.url.host, environment.baseHost).toHttpUrlOrNull()

    val newRequest = request
        .newBuilder()
        .url(replacedUrl ?: originalRequest.url)
        .build()

    return@Interceptor chain.proceed(newRequest)
}

This interceptor gets added to the okHttpClient and the retrofit instance created as so:
private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)// the interceptor created above
        .let(retrofitInterceptor::configureOkHttp)
        // blabla more config
        .build()

    internal val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(environment.baseUrl)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        // blabla more config
        .build()

Problem: val replacedUrl defined above, looks exactly the same (in terms of string-comparison) as originalRequest.url. However, all the requests that have a replaced URL, will fail with error code 400.
I can assume that, even if the URL strings are the same, the URL objects are not. I don't exactly understand, why the new replacedUrl doesn't work?
How can I properly override the .baseUrl(environment.baseUrl) I used to create the retrofit object?
